# Making my Flex Canvas Transparent

Tags: apache-flex

Good Morning Stackoverflow
I would like to ask a question....how do you make your mx:Canvas transparent

mx:Canvas includeIn="menugamestate1" id="v1" width="500" height="500" backgroundColor= 'none'  borderStyle="none"  dragEnter="dragEnterHandler(event);"  dragDrop="dragDropHandler(event);" width.menugamestate1="1004" x.menugamestate1="10.4" y.menugamestate1="46.7" height.menugamestate1="437"

that was the sample

Comment: your states in the Canvas suggest that you are using Flex4, so you should avoid using the Canvas and instead using a Group or SkinnableContainer...

Answer (score 6):

Rather than setting backgroundColor to "none", set the alpha:

```
backgroundAlpha="0.0"
```

Hope that helps.